# Appsetting.json read value of key in Controller Class,Comes Blank?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .net core 2.0 application,I have created a appsettings.json file to store the configuration detail for the application.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "RestCalls": {
    "SFGetAllAccounts": "https://example.com",
    "SFGetIndividualAccount": "https://example.com",
    "B6GetAccount": "https://example.com"
  }
}
```

Equivalent .Net Class to Map values

```
public class AppConfiguration
{
    public string SFGetAllAccounts { get; set; }
    public string SFGetIndividualAccount { get; set; }
    public string B6GetAccount { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` Added the following configuration

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder =  new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("RestCalls"));
}
```

In the Controller Class, **When Post method is called in the _configuration object is initialized and is blank so all the property from this class AppConfiguration is null.**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IOptions<AppConfiguration> _configuration;
    public HomeController(IOptions<AppConfiguration> config)
    {
        this._configuration = config;
    }

    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]LoginModel model)
    {
        RESTCreatorHelper r = new RESTCreatorHelper(_configuration);
    }
}
```

I have searched a lot about this things on SO and tried many approaches nothing seems to work. Obivously i am missing something can you suggest **what is need for the values to be filled in _configuration object and also how should i access the property value.**

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works as expected for me. Have you checked that you have correct data on ConfigureServices step?

Comment: As a quick aside if this is an asp.net core 2 project generated from Visual Studio you don't need to explicitly create a `ConfigurationBuilder` any more. The functionality is now all taken care of behind the scenes in the `CreateDefaultBuilder` extension method on `IWebHost` which is used in `Program.cs`.

Further info here although the article talks about the beta version of asp.net core 2: https://andrewlock.net/exploring-program-and-startup-in-asp-net-core-2-preview1-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the file was inside a folder and it was not able to find the file . So I corrected the path

```
var builder = 
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("ConfigurationFiles/AppSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

and also added AddOptions which binded the values correctly.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("RestCalls"));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is probably to do with `.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)` which I believe will return to the `wwwroot` folder within the project and not the project root where `appsettings.json` sits.

If that's changed to `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` it will hopefully start working.

I believe that in in asp.net core 1 the content root path was normally set to the current directory when the `WebHostBuilder` was created but that's from memory and I could be wrong.